# How Can I Find Out When A Specific Line Has Been Added/Modified With Git?

Tags: git

I would like to know when a specific line in a specific file has been added/modified. Hence, I know the content of the line and would like to have the commit in which this line has been added/modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`git blame`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html):

```
git blame path/to/file -L17,18
```

Will show the history for line range 17-18.

Comment: Nice. Any idea why it shows the result for something like 20 lines if I just give it one line with `-L17`? I would expect that `-L17` gives the same result as `-L17,17`...

Comment: I think is its default behaviour. On the doc it doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574580/how-can-i-find-out-when-some-portion-of-a-file-was-deleted-in-git), which basically answers the same regarding the deletion of some lines, the answer is rather simple:

```
git log -S 'content of the line in which you are interested' <file>
```

Comment: `-S` will tell you which commits contain a specific line that was added or deleted, but ***not modified***. If you want to know when a line was last modified, `git blame` is the right tool for this, not `-S`.